# Add two arrays with incompatible dimensions that can't be broadcast

Tags: python, numpy

This seems like it should be a simple operation, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I have two arrays of incompatible shape that can't be broadcast together.

```
A1.shape == (2, 10, 10)
A2.shape == (2, 300)
```

I would like to add the two arrays along the first dimension, so that the result is an array with shape:

```
Result.shape == (2, 10, 10, 300)
```

In other words:

```
Result[0, 2, 3, 122] == A1[0, 2, 3] + A2[0, 122]
Result[1, 2, 3, 122] == A1[1, 2, 3] + A2[1, 122]
```

Can I do this vectorised, without resorting to looping?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. A1 has 200 values. A2 has 600 values. Your result will have 60,000 values. Where will the remaining roughly 59,400 values come from?

Comment: A1 has 2 * 100 values. A2 has 2 * 300 values. If we add along the first dimension, the result should have 2 * 100 * 300 values. Maybe there is some sort of combinatorial function to do this?

Comment: `A1[:,:,:,None] +A2[:,None,None,:]`  (2,10,10,1) broadcasting with a (2,1,1,300)

Comment: @hpaulj Brilliant! In other words, you can do this by adding dimensions using `numpy.newaxis` to pad the dimensions of the arrays until they can be broadcast. If you add this as an answer I will happily accept.

Comment: I understand now. I am going to reword the problem/solution so that it will be easier for others like me to understand it. Maybe it will help someone. For each value in the 10x10 matrix in A1, add it to each of the 300 values in A2. This gives a shape of (10,10,300). If we do the above for each of our two rows, we will get our shape of (2,10,10,300).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make numpy do the broadcasting, you should insert new axes to broadcast over. (this is pointed out by Heisenbugs in the comments)

```
Result = A1[:,:,:,np.newaxis] +A2[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis,:]
```

Do note that `np.newaxis is None`, so you can write `None` if you like. But I think `np.newaxis` is more readable.